# Trying to cd into c89 directory in my Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, linux

I am a beginner to raspberry pi.

So, I am trying to put a sample code using C in raspbian in my RP4

I was successfully able to cd into /usr, and then /bin.

So now my bash shows up as: "pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $"

I did ls and c89 is one of the directories since it is highlighted in blue.

I was going to do python, but I actually feel more comfortable using C. I was able to get into the python directory using "sudo sh -c python"

I tried using the same command but c89 instead of python. However, when I do that it gives me gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

I tried cd /c89 since I was already in the bin directory.

How can I get into c89 directory so I can put in sample code? Thanks

Comment: try cd c89 without the slash since you are in the directory that is the parent of the c89 directory. cd /c89 is looking for a c89 directory in the root folder (which probably doesn't exist).

Comment: Normally I develop programs in the home directory of the user and leave the compiler directories alone.  Any reason this should go in the compiler area?

Comment: Hi @SteveRobillard. Yes I've tried that already and it did not work.

Comment: What was the command you did that gave you the fatal error? Looks like you didn't provide files as arguments.
And what exactly are you trying to do? You shouldn't be placing loose .c files in /usr/bin

Answer (score 2):

There are some important issues I see so far. You are trying to do development in `/usr/bin` or in a subdirectory of it. I strongly recommend not to do it. `/usr/bin` is one of the most important directories of the operating system. It contains your programs, also important system programs and some may have special access rights. Doing development here with uncompleted programs and try and error you risk to break you whole operating system.

On my default Raspberry Pi OS there is no directory `/usr/bin/c89`. I don't know where do you get it. Because you cannot change to it with `cd /usr/bin/c89` may also be a hint not to do it as normal user. I seems it is protected with restricted access. Show it with `ls -ld /usr/bin/c89`.

You try to change to the python directory with `sudo sh -c python`. But this does not change to a directory. It starts the **python** interpreter with superuser rights (root). You are comfortable with **C** where you have to compile and link programs. But python is an interpreter that do not need that. It executes its statements direct within its interactive interface. With the command you are using you just call this interface but do not change to a directory. This also explains why `sudo sh -c c89` does not work. There is no program `c89` that can be run with `sudo sh -c`.

With the command itself are also some problems. You should not use `sudo` to run python for development. Python is intended not to need superuser rights to run. Otherwise a program that becomes wild may destroy your operating system. With calling `python` you will start **python version 2.7**. This is deprecated since years and has lost any support at 2020-01-01. I strongly recommend to use **python version 3.x**, called with:

```
rpi ~$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello world")
hello world
>>>
```

No compilation needed for "hello world".

I suggest to use a directory in the home directory, e.g. `~/devel` or ~/src`:

```
rpi ~$ cd
rpi ~$ mkdir devel
rpi ~$ cd devel
```